# how to update or remove the nested object inside ngrx entities?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-entity

how to update or remove nested object inside ngrx entities for example I want to delete the first element which has the 19 id from (charter.entities.scopes.data) as it shown in the bellow stored json object inside my ngrx store

```
 charter: {
      ids: [
        1
      ],
      entities: {
        '1': {
          id: 1,
          projectName: 'Some Project',
          projectCode: '899',
          projectUniqueCode: '674a9596-50ee',
          projectStatus: 'construction',
          budgetCode: 'CC34',
          projectTypeOne: 'Goods',
          projectTypeTwo: 'New',
          donorName: 'Elza Hills',
          scopes: {
            data: [
              {
                id: 19,
                module: 'Miss Cassandra Cartwright I',
                description: 'In tempore quia asperiores aut ea cum optio minima nemo est et aspernatur est repudiandae voluptas ipsum.',
                time: '2018-01-23 15:37:36'
              },

              {
                id: 43,
                module: 'Leanne Douglas',
                description: 'Occaecati facere eligendi esse esse nostrum in et vitae assumenda molestias omnis quis sit qui aut omnis est.',
                time: '2018-01-23 15:37:36'
              },
            ]
          },
          assumptions: {
            data: [
              {
                id: 29,
                assumption: 'Doloremque quo nihil minima ad optio perspiciatis asperiores debitis mollitia at debitis porro quia nam accusantium illo consequatur labore cum.',
                comments: 'Inventore ut pariatur id laboriosam recusandae soluta quo sunt impedit aut velit.'
              },
              {
                id: 164,
                assumption: 'Dolores quam aut possimus sint fugiat natus quos quaerat saepe facilis harum molestiae.',
                comments: 'Cumque quis magni illo dolore quas nam officiis dolores enim soluta doloribus in sed eum ut sunt.'
              },
            ]
          },
```

The Reducer

```
export interface State extends EntityState<ProjectsCharter> {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isLoaded: boolean;
  selectedProjectsId: any;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<ProjectsCharter> = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (state: ProjectsCharter) => state.id,
  sortComparer: false
});

export const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({
  isLoading: false,
  isLoaded: false,
  selectedProjectsId: null
});

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: CharterActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CharterActionTypes.loadCharterSuccess:
      return {
        ...adapter.addOne(action.payload['data'], state),
        isLoading: false,
        isLoaded: true
      };
    case CharterActionTypes.updateScopeOnParent:
      const scopeEntity = { ...state.entities[action.payload.param] };
      scopeEntity.scopes.data = scopeEntity.scopes.data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          item.module = action.payload.module;
        }
        return item;
      });

      return {
        ...adapter.updateOne(scopeEntity, state)
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
}
```

I can update and modify the nestad object with this reducer but the problem is 1- it's a little bit complex and also show me in terminal in compile time `error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Scope'.` also `Argument of type '{ id: string; projectName: string; projectStatus: string; projectCode: string; projectUniqueCode:...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Update<ProjectsCharter>'.`

Comment: if needed please tell me to share the Model and reducer code as well

Comment: Off the top of my head, this should be as easy as modifying the entities object. Please share the reducer in case there is a deeper issue.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I have updated the question and included the reducer with my concern please check

Answer (score 10):

I strongly advice you to change your store and normalize it. Take a look here: https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

With this approach you will have less complex reducers, as explained here
https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html

With a store shaped this way, you will have to build a complex reducer.

Comment: The links are now available under:

[normalizing state shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)
and
[updating normalized data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/updating-normalized-data)

Answer (score 4):

According to my logic, the following reducer mods should at least eliminate the **TS2339** error.

This bit

> Argument of type '{ id: string; projectName: string; projectStatus: string; projectCode: string; projectUniqueCode:...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Update'

is just telling you (in a non-helpful way) that `adapter.updateOne` is requiring a first parameter of pattern `{ id, changes }` but you are just giving it `changes`.

```js
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: CharterActions) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case CharterActionTypes.loadCharterSuccess:
      ...

    case CharterActionTypes.updateScopeOnParent:

      const id = action.payload.param;
      const entities = {...state.entities};
      const original = entities[id];

      const newScopes = original.scopes.data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          item.module = action.payload.module;
        }
        return item;
      });
      const changes = { scopes: { data: newScopes }} // Partial<ProjectsCharter>

      return {
        ...adapter.updateOne({ id, changes }, state)
      };
    }

    default:
      ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this by saying the ideal solution is to normalize your entities with something like [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).  That said, here is a solution that works for me:

1. Make a deep clone of the state object
2. Use the Javascript `delete` method on the cloned object
3. Pass this new object as the new state

So let's assume your state looks something like this:

```js
{
  entities: {
   '1': {
     prop1: 'val1',
     nested: {
      '1': {
        prop1: 'val1'
      },
      '2': {
        prop2: 'val2'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If your goal is to delete `entities[1].nested[1]`, just use the following code (note that I am using the [lodash library](https://lodash.com/)):

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash'

on(Actions.sampleDeleteAction, (state) => {
  const clonedState = _.cloneDeep(state);

  delete clonedState.entities[1].nested[1];

  return { ...clonedState };
}
```

Obviously, you would want to add `props` to your action that contain the necessary index values you are using to delete rather than explicitly using indexes as in the example `entities[1].nested[1]`.